# A CASPOL command to completely trust all code

Tags: .net, security, caspol

We have a a couple of old framework 1.1 applications at my workplace, and we have run up against security exception problems. At this stage, I don't have the option of upgrading the apps to use ClickOnce security.

What I am after is a CASPOL command that will just allow any .NET applications to run on the users machine, regardless of where the app is being loaded from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a caspol command I used for this purpose, although it was limited to a dedicated 'fileserver' for our .Net applications.

```
caspol -ag 1 -url file://\\fileserver\* FullTrust
```